# VBA - IF Statement not

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Below is my VBA Code that will label a Company Name if its "Climate", "ComRes" or "Remnants"

```
For i = startrow To lastrow
    Company = dbsheet.Range("E" & i).Value
    Office = dbsheet.Range("G" & i).Value

    If InStr(Company, "Climate") Or (Company = "CT") Or (Company = "DSN") Or (Company = "WR") Then
    Label = "Climate"

    ElseIf (Company = "ECRS") And (Office = "(Platform Level)" Or Office = "CM" Or Office = "CM Grantsville") Then
    Label = "ComRes"

    Else
    Label = "Remnants"


    dbsheet.Range("H" & i).Value = Label
    End If
```

My Main Issue is that if the company name falls under "Climate" or "ComRes", it does not give any label. Just Null. But it is working for "Remnants"

The results
[image: Here are the results]

Is there something wrong with if else part? Thanks!

Below is my whole code:

```
Sub Dummy2()

Dim dbsheet As Worksheet
Set dbsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("xc_Global_Address_List")

Columns("H:H").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove 'Insert Label Column
Range("H1").Value = "Filter Column" 'Rename Header as "Filter Column"

Dim startrow As Long, lastrow As Long
startrow = 2
lastrow = dbsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'lastrow

Dim i As Long, Label As String
Dim Company As String
Dim Office As String

For i = startrow To lastrow
    Company = dbsheet.Range("E" & i).Value
    Office = dbsheet.Range("G" & i).Value

    If InStr(Company, "Climate") Or (Company = "CT") Or (Company = "DSN") Or (Company = "WR") Then
    Label = "Climate"

    ElseIf (Company = "ECRS") And (Office = "(Platform Level)" Or Office = "CM" Or Office = "CM Grantsville") Then
    Label = "ComRes"

    Else
    Label = "Remnants"


    dbsheet.Range("H" & i).Value = Label
    End If


Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I adjust your indenting slightly:

```vb
For i = startrow To lastrow
    Company = dbsheet.Range("E" & i).Value
    Office = dbsheet.Range("G" & i).Value

    If InStr(Company, "Climate") Or (Company = "CT") Or (Company = "DSN") Or (Company = "WR") Then
        Label = "Climate"
    ElseIf (Company = "ECRS") And (Office = "(Platform Level)" Or Office = "CM" Or Office = "CM Grantsville") Then
        Label = "ComRes"
    Else
        Label = "Remnants"
        dbsheet.Range("H" & i).Value = Label
    End If
Next i
```

Then you *should* be able to see that the line `dbsheet.Range("H" & i).Value = Label` is **inside** the `If` statement instead of **outside** it:

```vb
For i = startrow To lastrow
    Company = dbsheet.Range("E" & i).Value
    Office = dbsheet.Range("G" & i).Value

    If InStr(Company, "Climate") Or (Company = "CT") Or (Company = "DSN") Or (Company = "WR") Then
        Label = "Climate"
    ElseIf (Company = "ECRS") And (Office = "(Platform Level)" Or Office = "CM" Or Office = "CM Grantsville") Then
        Label = "ComRes"
    Else
        Label = "Remnants"
    End If
    dbsheet.Range("H" & i).Value = Label
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks @Chronocidal. It works! just a misplaced line... geez.. I thought it will produce the same results.